# How I can execute code pararelly or multithread

Tags: python, multithreading

The following code works for me, the problem is that each thread has to wait until throws to end or at least the perception that I have because when I put the sleep (10) the waiting time is indicated and then continuous.

What I wish is that the haul thread without having to wait for the internal code to run.

**It is my code (example):**

```
import threading
from time import sleep

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, num):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.num = num

    def run(self):
        print "I'm the thread", self.num
        sleep(10)
        print "I'm the thread, after 10 seg"


print "I'm the main thread"
for i in range(0, 10):
    t = MyThread(i)
    t.start()
    t.join()
```

Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 `for` loops: 1 to start the threads and one to wait for them:

```
# create all threads
ts = [MyThread(i) for i in range(10)]

# start all threads
for t in ts:
    t.start()

# wait for all threads
for t in ts:
    t.join()
```